# How to properly time data rendering in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, react-props

I am attempting to pull data from Open Data to put together a quick heat map. In the process, I want to add some stats. Almost everything runs well in that I have the data and am able to render the map, but I am unsure how to deal with calculations once I get the data since it takes time for data to come in. How do I set things up so that I can run a function on a state variable if it hasn't necessarily received data yet? Currently I am getting a `null` as the number that is passed as props to `StatCard`.

Below are my attempts:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Leaf from './Leaf';
import Dates from './Dates';
import StatCard from './StatCard';
import classes from './app.module.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:[],
      cleanData:[],
      dateInput: '2019-10-01',
      loading: false,
      totalInspections: null,
      calculate: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      this.fetchData();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      })
    }
  }


  fetchData=()=>{
    const requestData = async () => {
      await fetch(`https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/p937-wjvj.json?$where=latitude > 39 AND latitude< 45 AND inspection_date >= '${this.state.dateInput}'&$limit=50000`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res =>
          //console.log(res)
          this.setState({ data: res, loading: true})
        )
    }

    const  calculateInspections = () => {
      this.setState({totalInspections: this.state.data.length})
    }

    //call the function
    requestData();

    if(this.state.data) {
      calculateInspections();
    }
  }

  handleDateInput = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({dateInput:e.target.value, loading: false}) //update state with the new date value
    this.updateData();
    //this.processGraph(e.target.value)
  }

  updateData =() => {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  LoadingMessage=()=> {
    return (
      <div className={classes.splash_screen}>
        <div className={classes.loader}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }


  //inspection_date >= '${this.state.dateInput}'& 
 // https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/p937-wjvj.json?$where=inspection_date >= '2019-10-10T12:00:00' 

  render() {



    return (
      <div>

        <div>{!this.state.loading ? 
              this.LoadingMessage() : 
              <div></div>}
        </div>
          
        {this.state.totalInspections && <StatCard totalInspections={this.state.totalInspections} /> }
          
          <Dates handleDateInput={this.handleDateInput}/>
          <Leaf data={this.state.data} />
          
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**StatCard.js**

```
import React from 'react';


const StatCard = ( props ) => {
    
    return (
        <div >
            { `Total Inspections: ${props.totalInspections}`}
        </div>
    )
};

export default StatCard;
```

**Attempt Repair**

```
   componentDidMount() {
    try {
      this.fetchData();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      })
    }
  }


  componentDidUpdate () {
    if(this.state.data) {
      this.setState({totalInspections: this.state.data.length})
    }
  }

  fetchData= async ()=>{
    const requestData = () => {
    fetch(`https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/p937-wjvj.json?$where=latitude > 39 AND latitude< 45 AND inspection_date >= '${this.state.dateInput}'&$limit=50000`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res =>
          //console.log(res)
          this.setState({ data: res, loading: true})
        )
    }
    //call the function
    await requestData();
   
  }
```

Comment: Is `this.setState({ data: res, loading: true})` a typo in the `requestData` function? shouldn't `loading` be set to `false` when the data is fetched?

Comment: yeah its a typo

Comment: Are you sure the use of query parameters is corresponding with the API documentation?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the code the data is fetched, that is not the problem. I have the data. The issue is I am unsure where and when to run calculateInspections() because it needs to run when I have received all of the API data and then be passed as props to the statCard.

Comment: Please send me the codesandbox link

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is that `isLoading` state needs to be set **synchronously** before any async calls.

So in your `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    try {
      this.setState({ loading: true }); // YOU NEED TO SET TRUE HERE
      this.fetchData();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      })
    }
}
```

This ensures loading as soon as you make the call.
Then your call is made and that part is **asynchronous**.
As soon as data comes through, the loading is done:

```
.then(data => {
  this.setState({
    data: data,
    loading: false, // THIS NEEDS TO BE FALSE
    totalInspections: this.state.data.length
  })
})
```

Furthermore, your `render` method can have multiple return statements. Instead of having conditional JSX, return your loading layout:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
        return <div> I am loading </div>
    }

    return <div> Proper Content </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only render `<StatCard />` if you have the data you need:

```
{this.state.totalInspections && <StatCard totalInspections={this.state.totalInspections} /> }
```

Comment: I tried that but no dice. Also tried to run the calculation only if this.state.data exists within componentDidMount but no luck. What I get now is just the number 0 were the StatCard would be

Comment: I see, it's because you don't understand how promises/async behavior works. You need to `await requestData()` instead of adding it to the requestData function directly and add `async fetchData = () => {}`. Better yet, `fetchData` should only fetch the data and store it in state. Then you should use `componentDidUpdate` to trigger `calculateInspections()` only when `this.state.data` changes

Comment: Hey Chase, trying to operationalize what you pointed out, albeit I admit I'm still learning so not sure how exactly to implement. i added my attempt to my question if you could take a look and point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, I don't think you need a separate function `calculateInspections()`. You can put that logic in the `then` callback.

```js
fetchData = () => {
  fetch(`https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/p937-wjvj.json?$where=latitude > 39 AND latitude< 45 AND inspection_date >= '${this.state.dateInput}'&$limit=50000`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        data: data,
        loading: true,
        totalInspections: this.state.data.length
      })
    })
}
```

**Secondly**, setting `this.state.totalInspections` is effectively redundant, since you can simple do:

```
{this.state.data && <StatCard totalInspections={this.state.data.length} /> }
```

**Lastly,** avoid using `componentDidUpdate()` hook when you're new to react. Most of the time you end up shooting yourself in the foot.

Currently your Attempt Repair just got you into an infinite render loop. This happens because whenever you call `setState()`, it'll call `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle hook after rendering. But within `componentDidUpdate()` you **call again** `setState()`, which induces a follow-up call to the same lifecycle hook, and thus the loop goes on and on.

If you must use `componentDidUpdate()` and call `setState()` inside, rule of thumbs, always put a stop-condition ahead of it. In you case, it'll be:

```js
componentDidUpdate () {
  if (this.state.data) {
    if (this.state.totalInspections !== this.state.data.length) {
      this.setState({ totalInspections: this.state.data.length })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```js
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            dateInput: '2019-10-01',
            loading: false,
            error: false
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            await this.fetchData(this.state.dateInput);
        } catch (err) {
            this.setState({ loading: false, error: true });
        }
    }

    fetchData = (date) => new Promise(resolve => {
        this.setState({ loading: true });
        fetch(`https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/p937-wjvj.json?$where=latitude > 39 AND latitude< 45 AND inspection_date >= '${date}'&$limit=50000`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ data: res, loading: false, error: false });
                resolve(res.data);
            });
    })

    handleDateInput = e => {
        this.setState({ dateInput: e.target.value }) //update state with the new date value
        this.fetchData(e.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        const { loading, data } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                {loading && (
                    <div className={classes.splash_screen}>
                        <div className={classes.loader}></div>
                    </div>
                )}
                {data && <StatCard totalInspections={data.length} />}
                <Dates handleDateInput={this.handleDateInput} />
                <Leaf data={data} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of achieving this:

1. You can put calculator in `componentDidUpdate()` and write a condition to just calculate once

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const data = this.state.data;

    // this line check if we have data or we have new data,
    // calculate length once
    if (data.length || !isEqual(data, prevState.data)) {
        calculateInspections()
    }
}

// isEqual() is a lodash function to compare two object or array
```

2. You can stop your rendering until data is fetched

```js
async componentDidMount() {
      await fetchData()
    }

fetchData = () => {
    const requestData = async() => {
    await fetch(`https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/p937-wjvj.json?$where=latitude > 39 AND latitude< 45 AND inspection_date >= '${this.state.dateInput}'&$limit=50000`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res =>
        //console.log(res)
        this.setState({
            data: res,
            loading: true,
            totalInspections: res.length
        })
        )
    }
    // in above situation you just setState when you are sure
    // that data has come

    //call the function
    requestData();
}
```